# Changing type of input is not working in IE8 with replaceChild

Tags: javascript

I am using below code to change input type onfocus and resetting it to text onblur. But this is not working

HTML

```
 <input type="password" onfocus="changeInputType(this,'text')"
                        onblur="changeInputType(this,'password')">
```

JS

```
  function changeInputType(oldObject, oType) {
     var newObject = document.createElement('input');
     var wrapper= document.createElement('div');
     wrapper.innerHTML= oldObject.outerHTML.replace('type=password','type=text');
     var newObject = wrapper.firstChild;
     oldObject.parentNode.replaceChild(newObject,oldObject);
     return newObject;
  }
```

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/WfRFB/21/) is the fiddle. It is not working.

Comment: Your *fiddle* isn't working because you have the entire script wrapped in an `onLoad` handler, so `changeInputType` isn't a global function, so it can't be called from a DOM0 event attribute. (Wrapping in `onLoad` is bizarrely jsFiddle's default, you're not the first to run afoul of it.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Now fiddle will work

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to change the type attribute to password on blur and to text on focus, your code does not work for more than one reason.

1. You are missing the double quotes in your call to replace: `replace('type=password','type=text')`
2. When you call `replaceChild` the tag is removed and another blur event is triggered causing an error.
3. You are not using the `oType` variable anywhere.

Is easier to just use the type property like in the code below:

```
function changeInputType(oldObject, oType) {
    oldObject.type = oType;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK changing type from password to text does not work. It will silently fail.